# VKeyboard in kv file not work for TextInput

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I want to Write something in my TextInput Box with My VKeyboard in kivy language .
but it's not work.
I've use json for VKeyboard becouse I not found another way for it.
if you know how can I use VKeyboard plz tell me .

I want to use VKeyboard on .kv file

this is my code (kivy code with kv file ):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager , Screen
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.vkeyboard import VKeyboard

class StartTestBtn(Screen):
    
    def read_data(self):
        print(self.ids.ti.text)
        
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass        

Builder.load_string("""

#:import utils kivy.utils
<WindowManager>:
    StartTestBtn:

<StartTestBtn>:
    name: "startTestBtn"
    
    BoxLayout:
        cols:1
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width , root.height
        padding: 100, 300, 300 , 500
        TextInput:
            id : ti
            text : ti.text
            multiline:False
            size_hint_x: 1
            height: 50
            size_hint_y: None
            width: 200
            hint_text: "Enter User ID"
            icon_right: "account"
            font_size:24
            

    BoxLayout:
        cols:1
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width , root.height
        padding: 1000, 30, 30 , 400

    VKeyboard:
        layout: 'numeric.json'

""")
     

class Shenacell(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "BlueGray"
        return WindowManager()

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    Shenacell().run()
```

and this is my json file :

```
{
    "title": "Qwerty",
    "description": "A classical US Keyboard",
    "cols": 15,
    "rows": 5,
    "normal_1": [
        ["`", "`", "`", 1],    ["1", "1", "1", 1],    ["2", "2", "2", 1],
        ["3", "3", "3", 1],    ["4", "4", "4", 1],    ["5", "5", "5", 1],
        ["6", "6", "6", 1],    ["7", "7", "7", 1],    ["8", "8", "8", 1],
        ["9", "9", "9", 1],    ["0", "0", "0", 1],    ["-", "-", "-", 1],
        ["=", "=", "=", 1],    ["\u232b", null, "backspace", 2]
    ],
    "normal_2" : [
        ["\u21B9", "\t", "tab", 1.5],  ["q", "q", "q", 1],    ["w", "w", "w", 1],
        ["e", "e", "e", 1],    ["r", "r", "r", 1],    ["t", "t", "t", 1],
        ["y", "y", "y", 1],    ["u", "u", "u", 1],    ["i", "i", "i", 1],
        ["o", "o", "o", 1],    ["p", "p", "p", 1],    ["[", "[", "[", 1],
        ["]", "]", "j", 1],    ["\\", "\\", "\\", 1]
    ],
    "normal_3": [
        ["\u21ea", null, "capslock", 1.8],  ["a", "a", "a", 1],    ["s", "s", "s", 1],
        ["d", "d", "d", 1],    ["f", "f", "f", 1],    ["g", "g", "g", 1],
        ["h", "h", "h", 1],    ["j", "j", "j", 1],    ["k", "k", "k", 1],
        ["l", "l", "l", 1],    [":", ":", ":", 1],    ["'", "'", "'", 1],
        ["\u23ce", null, "enter", 2.2]
    ],
    "normal_4": [
        ["\u21e7", null, "shift", 2.5],  ["z", "z", null, 1],    ["x", "x", "x", 1],
        ["c", "c", "c", 1],    ["v", "v", "v", 1],    ["b", "b", "b", 1],
        ["n", "n", "n", 1],    ["m", "m", "m", 1],    [",", ",", ",", 1],
        [".", ".", ".", 1],    ["/", "/", "/", 1],    ["\u21e7", null, "shift", 2.5]
    ],
    "normal_5": [
        [" ", " ", "spacebar", 12], ["\u2b12", null, "layout", 1.5], ["\u2a2f", null, "escape", 1.5]
    ],
    "shift_1": [
        ["~", "~", "~", 1],    ["!", "!", "!", 1],    ["@", "@", "@", 1],
        ["#", "#", "#", 1],    ["$", "$", "$", 1],    ["%", "%", "%", 1],
        ["^", "^", null, 1],   ["&", "&", "&", 1],    ["*", "*", "*", 1],
        ["(", "(", "(", 1],    [")", ")", ")", 1],    ["_", "_", "_", 1],
        ["+", "+", "+", 1],    ["\u232b", null, "backspace", 2]
    ],
    "shift_2": [
        ["\u21B9", "\t", "tab", 1.5],  ["Q", "Q", null, 1],    ["W", "W", null, 1],
        ["E", "E", "e", 1],    ["R", "R", "r", 1],    ["T", "T", "t", 1],
        ["Y", "Y", "y", 1],    ["U", "U", "u", 1],    ["I", "I", "i", 1],
        ["O", "O", "o", 1],    ["P", "P", "p", 1],    ["{", "{", "{", 1],
        ["}", "}", "}", 1],    ["|", "|", "|", 1.5]
    ],
    "shift_3": [
        ["\u21ea", null, "capslock", 1.8],  ["A", "A", "a", 1],    ["S", "S", "s", 1],
        ["D", "D", "d", 1],    ["F", "F", "f", 1],    ["G", "G", "g", 1],
        ["H", "H", "h", 1],    ["J", "J", "j", 1],    ["K", "K", "k", 1],
        ["L", "L", "l", 1],    [";", ";", ";", 1],    ["\"", "\"", "\"", 1],
        ["\u23ce", null, "enter", 2.2]
    ],
    "shift_4": [
        ["\u21e7", null, "shift", 2.5],  ["Z", "Z", "z", 1],    ["X", "X", "x", 1],
        ["C", "C", "c", 1],    ["V", "V", "v", 1],    ["B", "B", "b", 1],
        ["N", "N", "n", 1],    ["M", "M", "m", 1],    ["<", "<", "<", 1],
        [">", ">", ">", 1],    ["?", "?", "?", 1.5],    ["\u21e7", null, "shift", 2.5]
    ],
    "shift_5": [
        [" ", " ", "spacebar", 12], ["\u2b12", null, "layout", 1.5], ["\u2a2f", null, "escape", 1.5]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very top of your python code, insert:

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode', 'systemanddock')
```

This will cause a virtual keyboard to popup for any widget that needs keyboard input.

Then, in your `kv` add a rule for `VKeyboard` to get your customized keyboard (you can leave this out to get the standard `VKeyboard`):

```
<VKeyboard>:
    layout: 'numeric.json'
```